# In-line block items are stacked on top of each other

Tags: html, css, inline

I've been fiddling with this bit of code for a couple hours now, and I can't figure it out.

I'm attempting to create a single line of navigation links (9 in total, if that's relevant), with the first link anchored to the left side of the screen and additional links to the right one after the other (like a line of text).

My links are all stacked on top of each other in the same spot. What am I doing wrong that they won't appear in a line?

```
.logo {
     font-family: 'Work Sans';
     font-weight: 100;
     font-size: 150px;
     color: #B5B5B5;
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: 25px;
     text-align: right;
}
 .logo::before {
     content: '////////////////////////////////////////////';
     font-weight: 300;
     letter-spacing: 4px;
     font-size: 25px;
     color: #ff00ff;
}
.navs a {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin: -10px 15px 0px;
    width: 135px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
    padding:6px;
    font:14px 'share tech mono';
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:#B5b5b5;
    text-align: left;

}
```

```
<div class="logo">
                    STICTION

                    <div class="navs"><a href="/">QUICK-START</a> <a href="/">RULES</a></div></div>
```

If this isn't enough code to diagnose the problem, I can provide more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of the problem is due to the ***'position: absolute'*** attribute for ***.navs a*** element.

**position: absolute;**

makes the element appear at the exact position on screen, 
thereby making different elements of the same class appear stacked one above the other.

**Problem can be fixed by**

1. Either removing the 'position: absolute'
   or
2. Changing the property to 'position: relative'

**More information on 'position' property:**

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp